# An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli' with ng serve

Tags: angular

I have taken checkout of angular project and trying to run `ng serve` with this command I am getting the following error.

```
 An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli'
Require stack:
- D:\PMSAngularProj\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js
- D:\PMSAngularProj\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\index.js
- D:\PMSAngularProj\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\angular-cli-files\models\webpack-configs\typescript.js
- D:\PMSAngularProj\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\angular-cli-files\models\webpack-configs\index.js
- D:\PMSAngularProj\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\browser\index.js
- D:\PMSAngularProj\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\dev-server\index.js
- C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\node-modules-architect-host.js   
- C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\index.js
- C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js
- C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\serve-impl.js
- C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\export-ref.js
- C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\index.js
- C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\utilities\json-schema.js
- C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js
- C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\cli\index.js
- C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\init.js
- C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng
See "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-6M2aBm\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "ng-pi-admin",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --base-href ./",
    "build:prod": "ng build --prod --base-href ./",
    "build:ci": "ng build --prod --base-href ./",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.2.10",
    "@angular/common": "^7.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.2.10",
    "@angular/core": "^7.2.10",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.2.10",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.10",
    "@angular/router": "^7.2.10",
    "angular-froala-wysiwyg": "^2.9.3",
    "animate.css": "^3.5.2",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "echarts": "^3.8.5",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "fontface-source-sans-pro": "^2.0.10-alpha1",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.3.0",
    "ng2-select": "^2.0.0",
    "ngx-echarts": "^2.0.0",
    "ngx-modal": "^0.0.29",
    "ngx-pagination": "^3.0.3",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "normalize.css": "^7.0.0",
    "pell": "^1.0.4",
    "roboto-fontface": "^0.8.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.4.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.0.0-rc.0",
    "sweetalert2": "^7.6.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1001.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^10.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.2.10",
    "@angular/language-service": "^7.2.10",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^5.2.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.2.2"
  }
}
```

I have tried to resolve by executing `npm i @angular/compiler-cli` command,

it has given me output like below

```
+ @angular/compiler-cli@7.2.16
added 1593 packages from 1243 contributors and audited 1603 packages in 317.518s

62 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

after that I tried to execute ng serve still getting the same error like

An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli/src/tooling'
Require stack:

Comment: Have you tried to delete node_modules and do "npm install"?

Comment: yes I tried with deleting and `npm install`

Comment: You may need the webpack: https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack

Comment: @CirrusMinor after installation of `npm install --save-dev webpack` also same error

Comment: I suppose it's a version mismatch between angular and angular/cli. Have you updated angular/cli alone?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

it is version mismatch, just update all dependencies with [npm-check-updates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates)

```
npm i -g npm-check-updates
ncu -u
npm install
```

Comment: Just to add to this answer. I had to delete package.lock.json, delete node_modules, and run the command `npm cache clean --force`. When I tried the above without the steps I have listed, it kept referencing old versions of packages that I thought were updated in the update, and came back with dependency issues.

Answer (score -6):

Run the

> npm install

before you run

> ng serve

you need to use sudo access, in some terminals.