# Angular Cannot find module compiler.mjs

Tags: angular

i tried to install angular cli it installed successfully.when i run the project i got the error was i attached below. i don't how to solve them.i cleared the cache also but couldn't successfully.

```
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'E:\angfo\my-first-project\node_modules\@angular\compiler\fesm2015\compiler.mjs' imported from E:\angfo\my-first-project\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\bundles\index.js
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
    at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:326:11)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:945:10)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1153:11)
    at nextResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:163:28)
    at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:838:30)
    at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:424:18)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:77:40)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
```

Comment: I had same issue and solved by this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63841959